# Why using Action in this code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, action, invoke

Hi 
I see following code:

```
void UpdateMessage (string message)
{
    Action action = () => txtMessage.Text = message;
    this.Invoke (action);
}
```

Why using Action and then invoke action here? Why not just using `txtMessage.Text = message` to replace the code in function body?

---

**Update**

A fuller version of the code, presented in a comment, reproduced below with syntax highlighting, indentation etc.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        new Thread(Work).Start(); 
    } 

    void Work() 
    { 
        Thread.Sleep(5000); 
        UpdateMessage("My Garden"); 
    } 

    void UpdateMessage(string message) { 
        Action action = () => textBox1.Text = message; 
        this.Invoke(action); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think what you've stumbled onto there is what we in the business call "bad code". It might have been copied from someplace in the system that actually needed indirection. But you are 100% right. This does not.

Comment: @Axeman How can you tell from the code supplied that UpdateMessage always runs in the GUI thread?

Comment: @Axeman this is not a "bad code", this is UI thread invocation.

Comment: Not to be confused with a action.Invoke() call

Comment: @David Heffernan, well that's the one thing I contemplated. But there was nothing there specifically that says that this is GUI code--and provided it is, and provided that updating the `Text` field is that laborious or dangerous as a background thread, why the hell hasn't the component chosen a safe/right way *itself*? It's still dumb code--whether it happens to be endemic or not.

Comment: @Axeman Those are just the rules of Windows. What alternative do you propose?

Comment: @David Heffernan, something that hides that kind complexity would be preferable. My first thought was that it was like a `DoEvents` in VB or a `window.setTimeout( 0 )` in JavaScript (which just queues the handler)

Comment: @Axeman it's pretty simple once you are familiar with the pattern

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because this code runs on a different thread from the UI and must be marshalled across to the UI thread with `Invoke`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for `Control.Invoke()` states:

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

This is all necessary because the underlying Windows framework requires that operations on a window handle are performed by the thread that owns the window handle.

Answer (score 12):

If UpdateMessage is called from another thread you need to Invoke into main thread in order to interact with GUI elements

If you use just `txtMessage.Text = message` you will get `CrossThreadOperationException`

Comment: Yes, this UpdateMessage is invoked in another thread other than main UI thread. But why I use txtMessage.Text = message and didn't see the exception which is supposed to be there? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should work with a control's properties in the UI thread, otherwise you will receive exception.

Control.Invoke() will execute your delegate by sending windows message to the window message loop.

But you can optimize code to prevent unnecessary thread syncronization when it don't required:

```
void UpdateMessage (string message)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((Action)()=>UpdateMessage(message));
        return;
    }

    txtMessage.Text = message;
}
```

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestAction
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   new Thread(Work).Start();
  }

  void Work()
  {
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   UpdateMessage("My Garden");
  }

  void UpdateMessage(string message)
  {
   Action action = () => textBox1.Text = message;
   this.Invoke(action);
  }
 }
}

Comment: In this code, you call UpdateMessage method from the thread that was started in from constructor. The Control.Invoke() call is nessesary in the current scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I know this is necessary now. But I just wonder why if I don't use it, I didn't see any exception.

Comment: Try start it under debugger, you should see that exception.